# How can I force `ispell` to reject a spelling?

Tags: spell-check

I want Linux `ispell` to reject the old-style spelling "parametrize" in favor of the more modern variant "parameterize".  I can add "parameterize" to my personal dictionary, no problem.  But how can I tell ispell to flag "parametrize" as misspelled, even though it is there in the system dictionary?